# How to convert an object of type Course to a Map<Integer, Integer> using Java 8 streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Suppose there are 2 classes:

```
class Subject {
    private int subjectId;  
    private String Name;
}

class Course {
    private int courseId;
    private List<Subject> subjects;
}
```

I want to convert a `Course` object into the `Map<subjectId, courseId>`. How can I achieve this using Java 8 streams?

Comment: It is not simply converting to List to Map, instead using other information(courseId) of the same object and then converting it into a Map<subjectId, courseId>

Comment: Do you want to convert a single Course object or a collection of Course Objects?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting a single Course object to the requested Map:

```
Map<Integer,Integer> map = 
    course.getSubjects()
          .stream()
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(Subject::getId, s -> course.getId()));
```

Comment: @Eugene `course` is the original `Course` instance for which the map is generated. I'm not trying to obtain it from a `Subject` instance.

Comment: @Eugene what do you think the OP wants?

Comment: @Eugene which part of "I want to convert a Course object into the Map<subjectId, courseId>" makes you think that?

Comment: @Eram me wrong - you right. will remove comments :)

Comment: @Eran, please mention in your answer that the `course` has to be *final* or *effectively final*

Comment: @ETO as soon as the OP would try to mutate the reference, he would find out about that :)

Comment: And if you have a collection of courses, you can create a Map with all SubjectIds for all courses with `flatMap()` in a single go

Comment: Suggestion: would make more sense if the getters could related to the exact field names as in question.

Comment: @nullpointer I guess it's a matter of style. Calling the getter of the identifier of a Subject instance "getSubjectId" seems redundant to me (subject.getId() clearly returns a subject identifier). Since the getters were not specified in the question, I took the liberty of assuming shorter method names.